# Swift в терминале

Tags: terminal, expressions, swift, math

Мне в терминале нужно решать математические выражения.
Например, если я захожу и пишу в терминале:

```
swift
import Foundation
2+2*5(exp*5(sin-M_PI)/2)
```

Но мне требуется сделать файл `File.swift`, с помощью которого в терминале я буду прописывать, например:

```
./File.swift “2+2*5(exp*5(sin-M_PI)/2)”
```

Он выдает ошибку:

> ./File.swift: line 1: import: command
> not found

Хотя файл `File.swift` имеет только строку `import Foundation`.

В чем проблема или я не в том русле думаю?

**Обновление**

Вот мое задание. От вас требуется скрипт на Swift (например, файл `calc.swift`), который можно запустить из консоли следующим образом:

```
chmod +x calc.swift 
./calc.swift “5+5*3 + 1” 
21
```

Если я просто в консоли захожу в swift:

```
swift
import foundation
5+5*3+1
21
```

то все получается.

Но если создаю файл calc.swift, в котором прописана строка `import foundation`, и пробую решить пример:

```
./calc.swift "5+5*3+1"
```

То выводит ошибку:

> ./calc.swift: line 1: import: command not found

В чем проблема?

Comment: Обновил комент

Answer (score 1):

Ты не сказал bash'у (или что у вас там в MacOS'и), чем твой скрипт открывать, вот он и пытается его исполнить как обычный скрипт для терминала.

Попробуй в самое начало файла вставить спецкомент, который скажет, чему скормить твой файл:

Пример файла:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift -i

<Твой код>
```

**Обновление**

Я swift никогда не видел и ванговать не умею, однако могу сказать, что, скорее всего, как и в любом другом языке программирования, в нем есть обработка агрументов.

Вот нашел вот это: https://medium.com/swift-programming/1-learn-swift-by-running-scripts-73fdf8507f4b

Парси по слову **Arguments**.

Я не знаю, зачем тебе решать в терминале мат. выражения, но для этих целей лучше подойдет Python с библиотеками Numpy и matplotlib.

Я лично предпочитаю все это дело (связку библиотек) в режиме с webgui на ipython: http://habrahabr.ru/post/218869/

Так я оформлял диплом и много чего еще.

---

**UPD**

В общем, ты можешь использовать классический eval. Точно не знаю, как правильно в swift реализовывать это, но можно поступить примерно так:

```
let expn = NSExpression(format:"3+3")
println(expn.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil))
// Вывод: 6
```

---

**UPD #2**

*Т.к. комментарии нельзя больше писать*

А что вам мешает проявить фантазию и заменить ту строку ("3+3") аргументом командной строки? Но данный подход достаточно небезопасен, т.к. не защищен от любых других команд я полагаю.

Comment: Мое личное мнение такого, что рано еще пользоваться этим языком, нужно мясцом ему обрасти, а с этим пока проблемы...

Comment: Если я задам свое математическое выражение в коде, то он его решает, а как сделать так, чтобы он считывал то, что я ввожу в терминале, заносил это в переменную и выводил потом результат этой переменной?

Comment: Я swift никогда не видел и ванговать не умею, однако могу сказать, что скорее всего как и в любом другом языке программирования в нем есть обработка агрументов.

Вот нашел вот это: https://medium.com/swift-programming/1-learn-swift-by-running-scripts-73fdf8507f4b

Парси по слову **Arguments**.

Я не знаю ачем тебе решать в терминале мат. выражения, но для этих целей лучше подойдет Python с библиотеками Numpy и matplotlib.

Я лично предпочитаю все это дело (связку библиотек) в режиме с webgui на ipython: http://habrahabr.ru/post/218869/

Так я оформлял диплом и много чего еще.

Comment: Но что-то не пойму логики, как это сделать. Как задавать аргументы так, чтобы он знал, что, например, скобки приоритетнее считать, чем просто от левого края до правого все вычитывать...

Comment: Хох, ну эту магию ты должен сам написать, не так ли?

Обычно для того дела AST(загугли это слово) юзают, это в принципе задание можно за час полтора сделать.

Comment: @rava

Обновил ответ

Comment: let expn = NSExpression(format:"3+3")
println(expn.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil))
Вариант типо такого может бы и подошел только мне же вводить требуется с клавиатуры в терминале а не в файле прописывать мат.выражение
Скорей всего нужен парсер какой нибудь либо все решать по методу Обратной Польской Нотации

Comment: @rava а в чём проблема считать строку `3+3` или любую другую из стандартного ввода, например, а затем просто подставить сюда?

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь файл `calc.swift` даешь ему права на выполнение `chmod +x calc.swift`. Примерно с таким содержанием:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift
import Foundation

let numericExpression = Process.arguments[1]
let expression = NSExpression(format: numericExpression)
var result = expression.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil) as! NSNumber
println("\(result)")
```

Заметь что тут нет обработки ошибок, количества аргументов и.т.д.